# How to find the last digits of 2^2009

Tags: algorithm, math, binary

I was using this formula to calculate last m digits of 2^n.

```
pow=2+(n-m)%(4*5^(m-1))  
ans =(2^pow)%(10^m)**
```

But this is not working for `n=2009` and `m=3`.
Suggest any error in my calculation or a better formula if there is.

Comment: In what way is it "not working"?

Comment: the last 3 digits of 2^2009 is 512 but the procedure is not giving same result

Comment: What language is this in? What are `n` and `m`? Why does the second line just end in the middle of an expression? Why isn't `pow` being assigned a value of 2009?

Comment: Can you explain your first statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what your formula is doing, but the simplest way is to calculate `(2^2009)%(10^m)` . Here is a pseudo code to find `(x^y)%mod` in `O(log y)`. Put `x=2, y=2009` and `mod=10^m`

```
power(x,y)
{
    if( y == 0)
        return 1
    temp = power(x, y/2)
    if (y%2 == 0)
        return (temp*temp)%mod
    else
        return ((x*temp%mod)*temp)%mod
}
```

Comment: I read that recursion formula fro modulo exponent topic on the net. But i was looking for what you gave me. thank you!